# SQL exception unhandled , invalid object name

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to get a query to execute on button click in visual studio 2010. As soon I reach the ExecuteReader statement, it says

> "Invalid object name 'task'."

The table name is task and the field name is task as well. The SQL connection runs fine. What could be the problem ?

```
        string MyConString = "Data Source=.\\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=filter;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(MyConString);

        string mycmd;
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd;
        //mycmd = "select task from task where task='" + textBox3.Text + "'";
        mycmd = "SELECT task.id FROM task WHERE task.task='plan1'";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(mycmd, connection);
        SqlDataReader sdr;
        string val = "";
        //try
        //{
        //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: Are you using a schema? If so, you may need to prepend the schema: `[schema].[table].[field]`

Comment: Side note: having fields in a table with the same name as the table is bad practice, and ugly.

Comment: i am using the inbuilt database provided with visual studio 2010.

Comment: Have you tried to make a fully qualified SELECT? `SELECT [task].[id] FROM [task] WHERE [task].[task] = 'plan1'`

Comment: yes, did try that. Getting the same SQL exception unhandled. Inavlid object 'task'. Can you please tell me what object 'task', is it referring to here ?

Comment: Surely is referencing to the database table `Task` or the column named `Task`. One of them, or both, doesn't exists (or the connection string don't provide access to them). Can you confirm that your database contains this table and, if exists, it has a column named task?

Comment: Check that the connected user has the SELECT right on the object.

Answer (score 0):

first suggestion is to change the columnname or table name from task to something else so keep the two different names but for a solution:

You could do with a table alias:

```
mycmd = "SELECT t.id FROM task t WHERE t.[task]='plan1'";
```

Comment: there was an issue with the connection string. thanks though :/ helped to debug.